# Mysql - double group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I've following query:

```
SELECT DATE(created) AS con_date,
       COUNT(*) AS con_per_day,
       GROUP_CONCAT(word_id)
FROM connections
WHERE created > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY con_date
```

Counts words added per day.

[image]

All good, but I want to count uniques! Note word_id has 14,14 in the last raw. This must be counted as 1.

I thought double group_by would cut it, but it seems to be a wrong way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `distinct`

```
    SELECT DATE(created) AS con_date,
           COUNT(distinct word_id) AS con_per_day,
           GROUP_CONCAT(word_id)
    FROM connections
    WHERE created > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    GROUP BY con_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to to use distinct where yous say what to count:
you would end up with:
  `COUNT(distinct word_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Add `distinct` both to the `count()` and to the `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT DATE(created) AS con_date,
       COUNT(distinct word_id) AS con_per_day,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct word_id)
FROM connections
WHERE created > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY con_date;
```